# How to center the marker exactly to center of Div in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How to set the marker exactly to the center of the map div block the marker moves to the right side and is not visible.

```
 <div id="map" #map >


 </div>
 this.map = L.map('map', {
  center: [20.5937, 78.9629],
  zoom: 5,
  zoomControl: true,
  trackResize: true,
});
const that = this;

this.map.flyTo(new L.LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629), 15, { animation: true });
```

> how to center exactly to center of the screen

Comment: Allways the marker is moved to the right side and i need to drag the map to view the marker. is there any possibility to set the marker centering the position of div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read out the center of the map. `map.getCenter()`

```
var marker = L.marker(map.getCenter()).addTo(map)
```

If you want that you marker is always centered, also after moving:

```
map.on('move',function(e){
  marker .setLatLng(map.getCenter());
  map._renderer._update();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/f0p5rj89/

Comment: Thank you. in addition to this while the marker is placed can the map be moved to the left some pixels is this possible?

Comment: Change your center latlng